# How to install aws cli inside jailshell

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have some files stored in a bucket on AWS S3 which I would like to access from a PHP application running on a remote webserver.  Unfortunately I am having troubling installing aws cli on the remote webserver as my hosting company has constrained me  within jailshell, so I can't run any install scripts; I have no ssh access and can only upload software to the remote web server via FTP.  I can run scripts on the remote web server via cron jobs so I can do some automated execution within the jailshell but it's pretty limited

I tried doing an installation on my local machine with the awscli bundled installer, which limited the installation to a single directory /aws on my local machine, which I then uploaded to the remote webserver, but I ran into problems executing the aws commands from a script due to symlinks and PATH not set up correctly on the remote webserver.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html
explains how to set up the aws cli, but it doesn't work well in my situation where I can't run PIP, or even edit the $PATH.

Comment: Is Python available on the server? Can you run `pip install` commands? Alternatively, maybe you could write a PHP script (using the AWS SDK for PHP) to copy the files from S3? Longer term it sounds like you might want to consider moving your hosting so somewhere else like Amazon Lightsail that isn't as restrictive as your current host.

Comment: AWS SDK for PHP!  of course, that sounds like exactly what I need!